# LuaTeX strings and xspace

Tags: luatex, luacode, xspace

I am using lua code to automate recording todos that come up during meetings I take minutes of. For this I use `\luastringN` from the `luacode` package currently. However, I would like  to have all the 'text' macros expanded in my arguments, since this would make it easier to export these tasks to other programs without cryptic macros. I found that the macros containing `\xspace` cause issues when replacing `\luastringN` with `\luastring`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{luacode}
\usepackage{xspace}

\newcommand{\foo}{Expanded foo\xspace}

\begin{document}
  \directlua{\luastring{\foo}}
\end{document}
```

Error:

```
This is LuaHBTeX, Version 1.13.0 (TeX Live 2021/Arch Linux) 
 restricted system commands enabled.
(./main.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-10-01> patch level 4
 L3 programming layer <2021-02-18>
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2020/04/10 v1.4m Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/lualatex/luacode/luacode.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/ifluatex.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luatexbase/luatexbase.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/ctablestack/ctablestack.sty)))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/xspace.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-luatex.def)
(./build/main.aux) (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd))
! Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line 10.
<inserted text> 
\fi 
<*> main.tex
```

Comment: xspace is not expandable

Comment: what do you want the effective Lua string to be given the input that you show? `"Expanded foo\\xspace"` or `"Expanded foo "` or  `"Expanded foo"` any of those three would be possible by locally defining `\xspace` to have an appropriate definition.

Comment: The result should depend on where the macro is used, so `\luastring{\foo}` I would like to expand to `"Expanded foo"`, but `\luastring{\foo bar}` I would like to expand to `"Expanded foo bar". Could you point me to how to locally define xspace to something like that?

Comment: You can't really really do that, you can hold the `\xspace` in the string as in my first code below. To get the effect you want I would use the second definition so it expands to space then use a Lua gsub to replace any double spaces by a single space.

Comment: Ah okay. Thank you, I will use the idea you proposed then!

Comment: actually you want to delete the space in <space>[,.!?] rather than or as well as double space but you can get the idea (feel freel to post and accept a self answer if you push it through to a working example)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the comments and the answer of @David Carlisle, I have written the following solution:

test.lua

```
function xspace_trim(s)
    local res = string.gsub(s, " ([%p ])", "%1")
    local res = string.gsub(res, "^%s*(.-)%s*$", "%1")
    return res
end

function Foo(s)
  print("\"" .. s .. "\" --> \""..xspace_trim(s).."\"")
end
```

main.tex

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{luacode}
\usepackage{xspace}
\directlua{require "test"}

\newcommand{\foo}{Expanded foo\xspace}

\newcommand{\Foo}[1]{{\let\xspace\space\directlua{Foo(\luastring{#1})}}}

\begin{document}
  \Foo{\foo}
  \Foo{\foo bar}
  \Foo{\foo. bar}
\end{document}
```

Result:

```
"Expanded foo " --> "Expanded foo"
"Expanded foo bar" --> "Expanded foo bar"
"Expanded foo . bar" --> "Expanded foo. bar"
```

The function `xspace_trim` removes any double whitespace in the string as well as spaces before punctuation. It also removes any leading and trailing whitespace. The `\xspace` is locally defined as just a space. The lua code then takes care of any added spaces that were unwanted.

Comment: actually you should probably accept this as it's more useful to you and to future readers to have a positive answer rather than just "you can't do what you wanted" in mine, I can manage without the 15 points:-)

Answer (score 5):

`\xspace` is not expandable, so can't be directly used in `\directlua` (or `\write` or `\edef` or similar commands.

You can locally give it a definition that is safe in those contexts, depending on what result you want.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{luacode}
\usepackage{xspace}

\newcommand{\foo}{Expanded foo\xspace}

\begin{document}

\typeout{}

{\let\xspace\relax\directlua{print(\luastring{\foo} .. 1)}}

{\let\xspace\space\directlua{print(\luastring{\foo} .. 2)}}

{\let\xspace\empty\directlua{print(\luastring{\foo} .. 3)}}

\end{document}
```

Produces

```
Expanded foo\xspace 1
Expanded foo 2
Expanded foo3
```